# Zooming in and out calculation

Tags: c#, graph, coordinates

So I am attempting to create a little graph that I will allow the user to add random lines etc as a learning project. The most frustrating part is figuring out how to get the zooming in/out to work - I have my ZoomScale variable bound to the mouse wheel and it "works" but I would like to be able to label the axis depending on how much they are zoomed and calculate the distance measurement of it (meters, cm, etc, because I have a MM per Pixel variable as well so we should be able to calculate this) so it needs to be more of an exact science than just "it works"

```
double X1 = ((actualline[i].X1 + actualWidth - VisibleXMax - VisibleXMin) * ZoomScale); //Calculate modified coordinates based on
double X2 = ((actualline[i].X2 + actualWidth - VisibleXMax - VisibleXMin) * ZoomScale); //  window width, window height, Visible X/Y, and Zoom.
double Y1 = ((actualline[i].Y1 + actualHeight - VisibleYMax - VisibleYMin) * ZoomScale);
double Y2 = ((actualline[i].Y2 + actualHeight - VisibleYMax - VisibleYMin) * ZoomScale);
```

Instead of trying to work with that let's try with a simple 1 dimensional equation and I can re write that for x and y.

So lets say we have a 5 unit wide line in the x direction

```
. . . . .
```

Currently that fills up our entire screen (well the window actually). From 0 to 5 all the way across. Now the user scrolls in to zoom into the first 3 units. Now those 3 units should fill up the entire window since the user is zoomed into it. It SHOULD look like this across the window

```
. . .
```

So originially the line was x1 = 0, x2 = 5. 0 to 5. And since our window is 5 units wide it fills up the window. Now the user wants to only see units x1 = 0 to x2 = 3. 0 to 3. But we want these units to stretch across the window, so with some sort of zoom calculation (like above) we want to turn 0,3 into 0,5 using the available variables. The variables being:

Window Width (5 units in this case)

Original X1 and X2 (0 and 5 in this case)

Visible X min and max (0 and 3 in this case)

And a zoom scale which is 1 and increments be 0.05 each  time you scroll up.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @FirstStep OK sounds good! No rush!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I do mine. Follow the comments and let me know if you have any questions:

```
public void ZoomImage(int ScrollDelta)
{

    OldUnitInPixels = UnitInPixels; // UnitInPixels is something similar to what you called mm/pixel - we need to keep the old one

    if (ScrollDelta > 0) // this `if` means zoom in - the `else` means zoom out
    {
        if (ZoomLevel != 20) // to control my maximum zoom in (I want 20 zoom levels only)
        {
            ZoomLevel++; // increment zoom level

            UnitInPixels += initialUnitInPixels; // I add certain value when I zoom in - for ex: initially it was 3 mm per pix, on zoom in it would be 4 mm  per pixel
            dotSize++; // I want some points to increase in size a little bit
            lineSize += 0.1; // I want some liness to increase in size a little bit


            // adjust all coord (points)
            for (var i = 0; i < DisplayedCoords.Count; i++)
            {
                DisplayedCoords[i].X -= XCoordOffset; // remove value of what you called VisibleX from current x value - means go back to the very original coord - ex: actual value is (1,1) but I added (49, 49) for it so it looks (50,50) better on the screen. So I want to remove whatever I added which is (49,49)
                DisplayedCoords[i].Y -= YCoordOffset; // remove value of what you called VisibleY from current Y value

                DisplayedCoords[i].X /= OldUnitInPixels; // divide by old 
                DisplayedCoords[i].Y /= OldUnitInPixels;

                DisplayedCoords[i].X *= UnitInPixels; // multiply by new
                DisplayedCoords[i].Y *= UnitInPixels;

                DisplayedCoords[i].X += XCoordOffset; // add back whatever we removed earlier. So it looks back again "better"
                DisplayedCoords[i].Y += YCoordOffset;
            }
            DrawImage(); // draw
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // else is super similar but instead of all the (++)s I do (--)s
    }
}
```

See it working: (zoom in/out from/on mouse position was not finished)

[image]

Comment: How are you handling the scrolling around? I see in your code it doesn't look at the window width/height. And in my version I keep the actual values in its own collection so I do not need to add/sub an offset since I have the real values stored separate.

Comment: I will assume that you mean Panning. Panning is a different feature than Zooming. It is super complicated but you can give it a shot if you liked it. The code here is just "_Input: Mouse scroll value and output: Different scale_" while Panning has "_Input: Click, Mouse Speed, Mouse StartPosition, Mouse CurrentPosition and Output: Different View_"

Comment: I see. In my code it is handled by the visible x min and max - as in when you pan the mouse it changes those values and that is where the lines are drawn. Should this logic be totally separate?

Comment: I did not completely understand your logic but it does not sound different no. There are some points that are visible and will hide on panning, and some are hidden and will be visible on panning. Also yes I have the original in a seperate container and I have DisplayedCoors which is what I display. I grab original and do calculations then populate DisplayedCoords and use it in DrawImage(). Sometimes apply some changes on the DisplayedCoords and sometimes I re-grab Original and apply some calc then draw.. and so on.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Thank you for the help I have a working version now and it just requires some tweaking! Thanks!